# How many functions such that the Image is a partition?

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory

$$[n] =\{1,2,....,n\}$$

$$f:[k]\rightarrow P([n])$$

How many functions are there such that: $Im(f)$ is a partition of $[n]$.

---

My approach:

Find the number of functions such that the cardinality of the $Im(f)=i$.
The total number would then be the summation from $1$ to $n$, but I'm having trouble finding the number of functions for a specific cardinality.

Comment: You ask how many ways there are to partition $[n]$ into $k$ nonempty labeled parts?  That would be ${n\brace k}k!$ where ${n\brace k}$ is the [stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  This is a quintessential problem in the [twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way).

Comment: @JMoravitz f is not necessarily a bijection, if n=2, k=2 if f(1)=f(2)={1,2} then the Image is still a partition, we get 3 total functions instead of 2

Comment: Fair enough... then you could chain this together with multiple of these.  Break into cases based on the number of parts in the partition, and then partition the available labels for use for said parts.